# ¿Cómo mapear un objeto y atributos del mismo que también son objetos con Automapper?

Tags: c#, poo, map, automapper

Tengo un problema con Automapper, es el siguiente, tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
public class OperatorsModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public CategoryModel KPI_CATEGORIES { get; set; }
    public OperatorTypesModel KPI_OPERATORS_TYPE { get; set; }
}
```

Y me gustaría mapearlo al siguiente objeto:

```
public partial class KPI_OPERATORS
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public virtual KPI_CATEGORIES KPI_CATEGORIES { get; set; }
    public virtual KPI_OPERATORS_TYPE KPI_OPERATORS_TYPE { get; set; }
}
```

Por lo que he creado la siguiente configuración:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<OperatorsModel, KPI_OPERATORS>());
```

Sin embargo obtengo una excepción:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Mapping types:
Object -> KPI_CATEGORIES
```

He intentado otras opciones como añadir más configuraciones con los distintos tipos pero ninguna parece haber funcionado.

¿Cómo puedo mapear un objeto que contiene atributos que también quiero mapear?

Answer (score 0):

es que el automapper no está encontrando o no existe la configuración de los otros mapeos, es decir debes de crear otras configuraciones de mappers de **CategoryModel a KPI_CATEGORIES** y **OperatorTypesModel a KPI_OPERATORS_TYPE**

```
CreateMap<CategoryModel, KPI_CATEGORIES>();
CreateMap<OperatorTypesModel, KPI_OPERATORS_TYPE>();
```